# How to get a list of Go dependents

Tags: go, github, dependencies

Short of building a dependency graph, is there an existing way to retrieve a list of dependent packages given a target package?

Sourcegraph has a badge (shield) that shows you how many packages use a specific package but when I click their link to go to their UI, I cannot find a count or list of packages. Here's more info:

- Sourcegraph article: https://about.sourcegraph.com/blog/see-how-many-people-use-your-library-with-sourcegraph-badges/

Example badge:

[image: Sourcegraph]

GitHub has a dependency graph but it doesn't appear to list packages for Go and its docs only mention JavaScript and Ruby per the following:

- GitHub Depends on: 
  https://help.github.com/articles/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on/

Comment: godoc.org can show a graph for any published package. It also has options to hide some or all standard library packages. Links are at the end of each page. https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux?import-graph

Comment: Interesting. I checked 3 packages and Sourcegraph shows higher numbers for all 3 packages than GoDoc. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: The GoDoc.org stats depended on the module being known to GoDoc.org. This happened only if someone is asking GoDoc.org about that package. Sourcegraph was probably more proactive at detecting published packages.
Nowadays [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/) is aware of modules because of the Go proxy.

Answer (score 5):

`go list` can do this for you, with use of the `-f` flag.

```
go list -f '{{.Imports}}' ./...
```

Will show a list of all imports for the current and child directories.  You can pipe this through `sort -u`, for example, to get a list of all dependencies, or do other standard shell-based massaging. Consult the [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages) for all of the formatting options available.

If you need a recursive list, this is also possible with some shell scripting, by then using doing the same thing recursively on the output of the above command.

Comment: Okay, have good results now, but some processing is needed. I'll play with this when I have more time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/) (provided by the Go team at Google) has that feature. Check the `imported by` tab.

Example: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dolmen-go/jsonptr?tab=importedby

[deps.dev](https://deps.dev) (also provided by Google) also has that feature for Go packages and also for other programming ecosystems.

Example: https://deps.dev/go/github.com%2Fdolmen-go%2Fjsonptr/v0.0.0-20200427210345-20e1608f9d85/dependents